# Create Graphics library like OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I was wondering how OpenGL and other graphics library's are written as wanted to create one of my own, not super complex 3D (for now) but more so basic window creation and plotting of pixels. I want to do this on windows but I also want to get around the whole windows API as it is slow, maybe by directly talking to the graphics card? I don't need any code but more so a place to start looking as the internet is full of these posts where people simply say use a pre-built graphics library which defeats the whole point, I want to do this to get a better understanding of how this is done, from the ground up in C++.

Comment: "a place to start looking" - **Open** GL - so it's opensource... why not its official site then?

Comment: You do realize that "creating a window and plotting pixels" is pretty much exactly what OpenGL is not?

Comment: OpenGL is implemented in the drivers for your graphics card, it is not a 3D engine.

Comment: @H2CO3: OpenGL is not opensource. It is "Open" like an "open industry standard", that is everyone can participate in its development. In fact OpenGL is an interface, with many proprietary (*and* open source) implementations.

Comment: It starts with creating the window and plotting to make these shapes, though it is normally fullscreen.

Comment: Check out this paper might be [useful](http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/publications/2007/bauchinger-2007-mre/bauchinger-2007-mre-Thesis.pdf)? By the way why custom?

Comment: It is clear you've misunderstood what OpenGL is and its purpose. As such your question is pretty unanswerable. Slavik's attempt is honourable but the main thing to take away is that you need to do a lot more research into how computer graphics work before you even begin to think about creating a graphics library. If you really are interested in using OpenGL to access the potential of GPUs, give [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut) a read first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both OpenGL and DirectX (specifically Direct3D) are ways of interfacing with your graphics card - short of also writing your own drivers, creating your own equivalent to the two isn't possible.

It is very possible to build a graphics engine on top of them, however. See some open-source projects like [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) and [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) for examples.

Also,

> I also want to get around the whole windows API as it is slow

Where does this misconception come from? Doing anything useful on your computer is going to eventually boil down to making system calls into your operating system.

Comment: I have been told that the win API is slow at drawing shapes, not all that slow but when you are calling it thousands of times each frame it adds up.

Comment: Ah. Using GDI, the Windows API's software method for drawing shapes, is slow because it relies on your processor instead of the graphics card. This does not mean the entire Windows API is slow, however.

Comment: Well that was what I was referencing, sorry about that.